# How to keep binary values in a Factor Variable?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm performing a toy example logistic regression.
What I would like to do is: *keep the factor variable* `a_fac` *performing as a binary variable*.

Here's my code:

```
set.seed(8)
a = rbinom( n = 10, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
d = seq(1:length(a))

a_fac = factor(a, labels=c("class1", "class2"))
plot(d, a_fac)

##Logistic Regression
lr = glm(a_fac~d, family=binomial(link="logit"))       ##cannot perform the log regression with factor var.
lr = glm(a~d, family=binomial(link="logit"))

##plotting
plot(d,a_fac, main = "logistic regression",  ylim = c(0,2))
lines(d,lr$fitted.values)

##this is the correct plot i want to obtain with the factor variable
plot(d,a, main = "logistic regression")
lines(d,lr$fitted.values)
```

[image]

Can I do this or I have to keep object of the same variable? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to convert `factor` to `numeric` for `glm`, i.e.,

```
glm(as.numeric(a_fac)-1~d)
```

such that

```
> glm(as.numeric(a_fac)-1~d)

Call:  glm(formula = as.numeric(a_fac) - 1 ~ d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            d  
    0.13333      0.08485  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  8 Residual
Null Deviance:      2.4 
Residual Deviance: 1.806    AIC: 17.26
```

Comment: Your guess is not correct.  You are performing LINEAR regression, since the default family argument for glm is "gaussian". OP wants to perform logistic regression, and asked for help with the plot.

Comment: Edward thanks for pointing this out but that was not the point of the question. I'm not asking how to make logistic regression. If I change to a logistic regression this still doesn't work. Just want to know if a factor variable can keep binary values

Comment: No. A factor variable cannot keep binary values (0, 1). As I said, factors are stored as integers starting from 1, with an associated label attribute. What you are trying to do doesn't make much sense. Your plot should use the original binomial `d` vector as the Y-axis, not your new `d_fac` vector.

Comment: Binomial `a` vector. 

Answer (score 2):

Your first glm model is NOT logistic regression since you did not include the family argument and specify "binomial".

```
lr = glm(a_fac~d) # Error!
```

The error is due to R trying to do a linear regression on a non-numeric outcome. The correct command should be:

```
lr = glm(a_fac~d, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

With plotting, factors are treated as integers starting with 1 for the first level. So if you want to use 0 and 1 for the y-axis, but have your labels attached, use the `a` version of your outcome vector, suppress the tick labels (`yaxt="n"`), and then add an axis with your own labels.

```
plot(d, a, main = "logistic regression", yaxt="n", ylab="Outcome")
lines(d, lr2$fitted.values, col="red")
axis(side=2, at=c(0,1), labels=levels(a_fac), las=1)
```